# Reverse homogeneous Sobolev Embedding

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.6146.pdf) about the Nonlinear Schrodinger Equation.

In **Remark 2.9**, the author mentions the following Sobolev inequality:
For any compact time interval $I$, assume $0 \leq \sigma < \rho$, $1\leq r, r_1, q \leq \infty$. Then, 
$$
\|D^\rho u\|_{L_t^{q'}L_x^{r_1'}(I\times\mathbb{R}^d)} \lesssim \|D^\sigma u\|_{L_t^{q'}L_x^{r'}(I\times\mathbb{R}^d)},
$$

provided $r_1 = \frac{rd}{(\rho-\sigma)r+d}$, where $q', r_1'$ and $r'$ are the Hölder's conjugates of $q, r_1$ and $r$, respectively.

I assume that she is using some *dual* Sobolev inequality
$$
\|D^\rho f\|_{L_x^{r_1'}(\mathbb{R}^d)} \lesssim \|D^\sigma u\|_{L_x^{r'}(\mathbb{R}^d)},
$$

valid for $\rho > \sigma$.

> **Question:** Does this inequality really hold? Could you give some reference or some idea about proving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\sigma=1$, $\rho=2$, and $d=2$. Then $r_1=\frac{2r}{r+2}>1$ provided $r>2$. So the inequality becomes (for functions depending only on space) 
$$\Vert D^2u\Vert_{L^{r_1'}(\mathbb{R}^2)}\le C \Vert Du\Vert_{L^{r'}(\mathbb{R}^2)}.$$ 
In particular, if you had a sequence of smooth functions with support contained in some ball $B$ and bounded in $W^{1,r'}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, then the sequence would be bounded in $W^{2,p}(B)$, where $p=\min\{r_1',r'\}$ and so by the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem up to a subsequence it would converge strongly in  $W^{1,p}(B)$ and the gradients would converge pointwise a.e. This is false. Take $u_n(x)=\frac1n \sin(nx_1)\varphi(x)$, where $\varphi$ is a smooth function which is one in $[0,1]^2$ and zero outside of $[0,2]^2$. Then  $Du_n$ is bounded uniformly in $L^\infty((0,2)^2)$ and so in any $L^{r'}((0,2)^2)$. But the gradients do not converge pointwise (not even up to a subsequence).

Comment: Thanks! The answer adresses the problem. Would you have some insight about the low-regularity case  $0 < \sigma < \rho < 1$, where Rellich-Kondrachov would not be available, and the derivatives are non-local?

Comment: You can still prove that the embeddings $W^{\rho,p}(B)\to W^{\sigma,p}(B)$ and $W^{\rho,p}(B)\to L^{p}(B)$ are compact. You use the fact that these spaces are interpolation spaces.

Comment: But would a similar counterexample work? The product rule is now an inequality, and the fractional derivatives are not compactedly supported anymore.

Comment: I think something similar might work, replacing $\frac1n$ with $\frac1{n^a}$ but it would be complicated to compute the double integral.